# Calling a stored procedure throws an error "Cannot change thread mode after it is set"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, biztalk

I'm getting this error when calling a stored procedure from my C# code from BizTalk. Not sure whether this exception is thrown from the stored procedure or my own code, as it is in BizTalk runtime debugging is hard.

```
public bool ProcessDigiMarket (int marketID, long ProcessID, string processName)
{
    try
    {
        string storedProc = h.GetConfigValue(marketID, processName, "SP_GetDigiMarket");

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(strcon))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            cmd.CommandText = storedProc;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Mar_Id", marketID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProcessID", ProcessID);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            InsertLog("ExecuteSP for process -> " + processName + " -> Execution Complete : " + storedProc, marketID, ProcessID);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        InsertLog("ExecuteSP for Process -> " + processName + " -> Error while executing SPDigiMarketQueue: " + ex.Message, marketID, ProcessID);
        throw new Exception("Error while executing DigiMarket SP: SPDigiMarketQueue \n"+ex.Message);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to debug this by attaching Visual Studio the the service of the host instance this runs under.  What happens if you run the SP directly? P.S. Why are you doing this in code rather than via a WCF-SQL port?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, This is a legacy app, and this issue happens only on production not in dev. So debugging is not possible. As I mentioned it is legacy app I cannot change it to   WCF-SQL port process.

Comment: Then you need to look at what environmental differences there are, especially with the database or database server